# Invalid sql statment

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to conduct an experiment using a pre-coded project which inside this link [here](http://secure-web.cisco.com/1NnBJdSVNaEyjhaRdE3hOaM-Oa3SjhrcSFCE4yv0k2QrGHNWXWrKsERh6xRvgf42N2sjDk8t25vGTvCcll4yMkqiBb4QYxPP5CYA4HllLyvv7T3Oj2Jd-7rMunpmIzXu8nOKqwz7v5HDH0S3PibvubIyoNQInN5IyrB3VXzebllRFSbptRFqGD-IxrQf5af2kmPpw-oWxyqhQPWOhEOVcQvBZoB1tVV6uPkcUK2_r2c8zXVe26TfF1IImC6KSZuMLuP6V0gOrGIYwotTV97JwZHX0TUnEYXzIy1fyZ87Ex1UDB-wzCTDrIkGdj_8maZNUGfrxWZTW8wefqkS9QlGPmqymP4GHA6nAOQJ1wPQ_w-UJBGK5kllrDaHrXWS1o6yW5kaP3xtvyKVypQvzyjT4pzxGkz7MpKAFhHa3_UP5cemqzn5vSHeCh6DyajK-dpNNcAKGroZrqt0FhXDvjIqr1A/http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.ubc.ca%2F%7Edtoker%2Fphd/VerbalWMTest.zip).

I'm using xampp as a web server with mysql. Whenever I run through the authentication page which has this code:

```
<?php
include_once("zSessionStart.php");
include_once("zConfig.php");
include_once("zDB.php");


$password = $_REQUEST["password"];
$userID = $_REQUEST["userID"];
$isAdmin = false; //is administrator or not
$askDemo = false;


    //authenticate the login data from login.php

    $query="select userID, isAdmin, askDemo from $_usersTable where (password= '$password') and (userID='$userID');";
    $rs=mysql_query($query) or die ("Invalid sql.");
            if ( mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0 ) //correct password
            {
                            $array = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
                            if(strcmp($array["isAdmin"], "y")==0){
                                $isAdmin=true;
                            }

                            if(strcmp($array["askDemo"], "y")==0){
                                $askDemo=true;
                            }

                            if(!$isAdmin){
                                $query="select userID from usertests where userID='" . $userID . "'";
                                $rs2=mysql_query($query) or die ("Invalid sql.");
                                if(mysql_num_rows($rs2) > 0){           //already take test
                                    $array2 = mysql_fetch_array($rs2);
                                    echo "<h2> You have already taken the task. Please contact your administrator if you " .
                                            " feel you need to re-take this task again.</h2>";
                                    die();
                                }
                            }


                            $_SESSION['userID'] = $array["userID"];
                            session_unregister('loginErr');


                            if($isAdmin){
                                header("Location: transfer.php?" . SID);
                            }else{
                                if($askDemo){
                                    header("Location:demo.php?" . SID); 
                                }else{
                                    header("Location: index.php?" . SID);                               
                                }
                            }
            }
            else
            {
                        $_SESSION['loginErr'] = "true";
                        header("Location: login.php");
            }



    mysql_close($db);
?>
```

I receive an error that says "Invalid sql.". Inside my database I have a table called users which has credentials such as userID and password. I've already set the username to be admin and password to be pass. However, I haven't had any luck figuring out what the issue might be.

Comment: Gah. The `mysql_*` functions are gone in modern PHP. They simply don't exist. You really should start over with a more modern tutorial. This one has major security vulnerabilities, too.

Comment: Invalid sql is coming because your table seems to be incorrect $_usersTable

Comment: @ceejayoz, I don't care that much about security since I'm not going to populate this on the web. Would you recommend that I use an old php web server ?.

Comment: @AmitGupta Gupta, Actually when I just used users as my table, I didn't accept it. I had to use the word Table next to users to get connected to the table.

Comment: @Yahyaotaif I would never recommend learning the *wrong* way to do things. Doesn't matter if it's going on to the web - practicing bad code means you accidentally write bad code when it **does** matter.

Comment: @ceejayoz you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Query is invalid because you are using wrong table name that is even no variable syntax i.e. `$_usersTable`. And also you are ending your query with multiple semi colons and even single/double quotes are not properly used.

You need to update your select query like below to resolve your issue:

```
$query="select userID, isAdmin, askDemo from usersTable where password = '".$password."' and userID ='".$userID."';
```

I strongly recommend you to use MySqli **Prepared Statement** Query to make it more **Secure** like below:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
$query = "SELECT userID, isAdmin, askDemo from `usersTable` WHERE userID=?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $userID);
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result();
$data = $res->fetch_all();
```

To learn more about it, follow link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @ Amit Gupta, thank you for responding. I still didn't go nowhere with this. The thing is the code isn't mine. It was developed in one of the university by a research group. I used the query you wrote but I get an error for the line after it. The error says : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Invalid' (T_STRING) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/verbal/authLogin.php on line 16. Also where would you recommend I place the MySqli prepared statement in this code. I'm using Xampp 1.8.2-6 for mac if that helps.